# DataFrame object has no attribute 'col'

Tags: apache-spark

In *Spark: The Definitive Guide* it says:

> If you need to refer to a specific DataFrame’s column, you can use the
>   col method on the specific DataFrame.

For example (in Python/Pyspark):

```
df.col("count")
```

However, when I run the latter code on a dataframe containing a column `count` I get the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'`. If I try `column` I get a similar error.

Is the book wrong, or how should I go about doing this?

I'm on Spark 2.3.1. The dataframe was created with the following:

```
df = spark.read.format("json").load("/Users/me/Documents/Books/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/flight-data/json/2015-summary.json")
```

Comment: can you show the code where your `df` dataframe is being created? specify language too

Comment: I updated my post as per your request.

Answer (score 17):

The book you're referring to describes Scala / Java API. In PySpark use `[]`

```
df["count"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. The book also covers Python and I thought they meant that the command works in both languages. But this is a good alternative.

Comment: In python I think you can also use dot notation, just omit the `col` part. So for instance, `df.count` is what you want

Answer (score 6):

The book combines the Scala and PySpark API's.

In Scala / Java API, `df.col("column_name") or  df.apply("column_name")` return the Column.

Whereas in pyspark use the below to get the column from DF.

```
df.colName
df["colName"]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Applicable to Python Only**

Given a `DataFrame` such as

```
>>> df
DataFrame[DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string, count: bigint]
```

You can access any column with dot notation

```
>>> df.DEST_COUNTRY_NAME
Column<'DEST_COUNTRY_NAME'>
```

You can also use key based indexing to do the same

```
>>> df['DEST_COUNTRY_NAME']
Column<'DEST_COUNTRY_NAME'>
```

However, in case your column name and a method name on DataFrame clashes,
your column name will be shadowed when using dot notation.

```
>>> df['count']
Column<'count'>

>>> df.count
<bound method DataFrame.count of DataFrame[DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string, count: bigint]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

... then continue

Answer (score 0):

**In PySpark col can be used in this way:**

df.select(col("count")).show()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).